# Comparing simple Python ctypes data types

Tags: python, ctypes

```py
>>> ctypes.c_ushort(37099) == ctypes.c_ushort(37099)
False
```

These do not seem to be equal because there are no comparison operators for PyCSimpleType objects.

Is there a reason why these are omitted? It seems that one must use:

```py
>>> ctypes.c_ushort(37099).value == ctypes.c_ushort(37099).value
True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`ctypes._SimpleCData`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._SimpleCData) and its superclass [`ctypes._CData`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData), "all ctypes type instances contain a memory block that hold C compatible data."

Presumably, each invocation of `ctypes.c_ushort(37099)` corresponds to a new memory block, thus making the equality comparison between them false. The documentation also notes that the `value` attribute contains the actual value of the object.

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> val1 = ctypes.c_ushort(37099)
>>> val2 = ctypes.c_ushort(37099)
>>> ctypes.addressof(val1)
2193186894992
>>> ctypes.addressof(val2)
2193186895376
```